# Changing datetime column to integer number without loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataset like this:

```
user_id      datetime
   1        13 days 21:50:00
   2        0 days 02:05:00
   5        10 days 00:10:00
   7        2 days 01:20:00
   1        3 days 11:50:00
   2        1 days 02:30:00
```

I want to have a column that contains the mintues, So in this case the result can be :

```
 user_id      datetime             minutes         
   1        13 days 21:50:00        20030
   2        0 days 02:05:00          125
   5        10 days 00:10:00        14402
   7        2 days 01:20:00          2960
   1        3 days 11:50:00          5030
   2        1 days 02:30:00          1590
```

Is there any way to do that without loop?

Comment: Uhm I don't think there's a way to calculate the minutes for every `user_id` and `datetime` without an explicit or implicit loop.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio Definitely true. But I'd guess the OP is probably just not being that clear, and what he doesn't want is an explicit loop, either to avoid breaking the array-processing style, or to get the speedup of letting Numpy/Pandas do the looping in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
df['minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.datetime) / pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')

>>> df
   user_id          datetime  minutes
0        1  13 days 21:50:00  20030.0
1        2   0 days 02:05:00    125.0
2        5  10 days 00:10:00  14410.0
3        7   2 days 01:20:00   2960.0
4        1   3 days 11:50:00   5030.0
5        2   1 days 02:30:00   1590.0
```

if your `datetime` column is already of dtype `timedelta`, you can omit the explicit casting and just use:

```
df['minutes'] = df.datetime / pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a special [`dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) for date/time series:

```
df['minutes'] = df['datetime'].dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

If you only want whole minutes, cast the result using `.astype(int)`.